# Logged into VSCode and now all of my settings are gone

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there anyway I can recover my settings.json? I logged in to my git in VSCode and my settings.json was replaced by a default one.

Comment: Figured it out myself. It actually does save a backup surprisingly. I'm guessing a lot of people hit this issue and they now save backups. ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/sync/settings/20210326T153134.json

Answer (score 0):

Found the backup here:

```
 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/sync/settings/20210326T153134.json
```

I'm guessing a lot of people hit this issue so they now save a backup.